# How to handle sequential database operations over a WAN efficiently

Tags: .net, database, latency

We have a .NET(C#) application that performs roughly 10-30 insert commands to a Sql Server database every second.  When the application was designed, the application(s) executing the inserts were on site with the Sql Server database, so network latency was not really accounted for.

Well at least network latency like you get over a WAN or over the internet was not accounted for.

The application performs these inserts sequentially.  So, if the 10-30 inserts ever take over 1 second, the application starts getting behind.  The buffering system we have in place only handles the occasional "hiccup" in network latency, assuming that the network latency will eventually even out and the application will have a chance to catch up.

In the case where network latency is constantly high enough for the 10-30 inserts to always take over a second, the application of course becomes unusable.

For the sake of this question, let's just assume that there is nothing we can do to reduce the network latency, or increase the sql server performance, or anything like that and that the 10-30 insert commands are always going to take over 1 second and cause the application to get behind to a point of failure.

Is there a good way in .NET or on the Sql Server itself to execute these commands in parallel so as to utilize bandwidth to help make up for latency?

I realize we could write our own system to handle all of this, but it seems like it would be a common problem with cloud database servers already.

I've read up on batching and utilizing transactions to send more commands at once over the pipe, but even doing this, it seems like it would eventually hit a wall if the network latency were high enough.

We want the application to tolerate higher and higher latency, but also not get too far behind on the inserts.

Comment: Is there anyway you can run SQLExpress locally and use SQL replication to handle the syncronisation for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no, we actually thought about doing that at first. We have a security constraint that the data cannot reside on disk locally and has to be transferred directly from memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are two techniques you can use that spring to mind.

**Batching**

Put all the inserts into one SQLCommand.

```
string sql = "insert into a (...) values (...);insert into a (...) values (...);.....";
```

This will have to be built dynamically, and unless the values are pre-cleansed you should use parameters instead of embedding the values into the sql. This will do all the inserts in one trip over the network, so minimising latency.
However, if the data you are inserting spans multiple tables which have FK relationships between them, and the FK in a child is an IDENTITY column in the newly inserted parent table then this won't work. However, all is not lost.

**Staging Tables with Batching plus an SP**

Create a set of tables containing the data you have to insert, but not including any FK relations that might actually exist in the final tables. Batch up inserts to insert your data into the staging tables and then call an SP which can move data from the staging tables into the final tables while preserving the relationships between them. This gets you down to two network round trips instead of 10 to 30 which should help.

Comment: With SQLServer you can actually combine those inserts into one statement.  `insert into a (...) VALUES (...),(...),(...)`